# setInterval task is consuming WAY too much CPU

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cpu, intervals

I recently created a bot in node.js, but its super super heavy, uses 100% cpu! I use node-fetch, async.parallel and setInterval, im not sure why it uses 100% cpu, it might be maybe because setInterval queues? Idk. Here is my code though:

```js
async.parallel({
  task1: function () {
    setInterval(function () {
      let itemRandomizer =
        config.generalInfo.itemList[
          Math.floor(Math.random() * config.generalInfo.itemList.length)
        ];
      let cookieRandomizer =
        randomCookies[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomCookies.length)];
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        agent,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          cookie: `cookie=${cookieRandomizer}`,
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          checks++;
          //console.log(checks, itemRandomizer, json.data[0].price)
        })
        .catch((err) => {});
    }, 0);
  },
  task2: function () {
    /* same code as task 1 (total 20 tasks) */
  },
});
```

I do not want to increase the interval, want it to stay as fast as it can, but 100% cpu is unreal, i dont want it to use that much, any work around? Is setInterval cpu-intensive?
Threads consume more CPU than async.parallel, so thats why i dont use threads.

Comment: So you're starting 20 tasks that each start an interval timer with the minimum possible delay between intervals. That's going to be significantly faster than the latency (round-trip time) of your `fetch()` calls. Thus your code is piling up HTTP requests pretty much as fast as it can.

Comment: how would I achieve this? What can I do so it does not keep stacking up @Pointy

Comment: Well what exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to not lose speeds, but should use less cpu, im fine with it using less cpu but more threads, but 20 is too little for me

Comment: You realize that the `fetch()` calls are asynchronous; the call to `fetch()` returns immediately but the HTTP request finishes when it finishes, at which point the `.then()` callbacks are invoked. The interval function does not wait for that to happen (and it can't).

Comment: so how would I prevent this?

Comment: _"Im trying to not lose speeds"_... that does not describe at all what you're trying to do. What is the intention of this application? It looks like you want to continuously poll URLs. Should each poll request wait for the previous to complete? Should anything happen to stop polling? How should errors be dealt with?

Comment: I hired someone on fiverr to make a website with apis, im checking the durability of those apis as he said it can handle a lot of requests and block bots

Answer (score 2):

You're using setInterval with a delay of zero, therefore you are scheduling basically infinite tasks to run. That's crazy. What you probably want is to start a new task only after one task is done (or maybe start a few, but at some point wait until at least one task is completed).

By the way, consider using something like [p-map](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-map) so that you can easily configure concurrency to a value like 20 instead of trying to basically re-implement what p-map already does.

Comment: How would i achieve this?

Comment: @cooldevnocap I've edited my answer, looks like p-map is exactly what you are looking for, using the `{ concurrency: 20 }` option.

Comment: Thank You I will test it out :). It wont lose speeds right? And if I do make more threads it wont consume as much cpu as it was before?